"Moon Dog" werewolf movie
I caught part of this on late night television (in Canada) sometime in the early 90s.  It was in English, and I believe it was in colour, but because it was high contrast night scenes it had a feeling of being in black and white. 
It felt like a contemporary film, it was not a classic. It had a dark brooding kind of mood too it, with slow pacing.
The scenes I specifically remember are an old(er) man referring to the "Moon Dog" coming at the full moon, possibly in a sort of broken english. The phrase Moon Dog really stuck with me.
There was a shot where the camera panned along human footprints in the mud (maybe a swamp?) and the footprints transition into large paw prints. 
A younger character building a sort of dome shaped cage out of sharp white sticks and branches and sitting inside (maybe shirtless), presumeably as protection against the "Moon Dog".  I think this was setting the stage for the final showdown of the film.
I think this "cage" was in the same swamp/mud where they showed the footprints
Some of the characters/actors may have been of Native American descent, but I'm not certain about that part of my recollection.
Possibly made for TV, or just an obscure low budget thriller/horror. I don't think it was a mainstream film. 

Nice job with the details! I was thinking it was one of the "Skinwalker" movies (since "Skinwalker" has been considered a Native American term for shapeshifter), but I don't think the movies' release dates line up with when you saw this one.
